# Prove, if $n>6$ is an even, perfect number, then $n\equiv4 \pmod 6$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, perfect-numbers

I've been working on this for quite awhile, and am stumped after a little bit. I have some stuff written down, but I just don't know how to completely prove it. I don't have much done yet:

- $(2^{p-1})(2^p -1)$
- $(2^{p-1})(2^p -1)\equiv 4 \pmod 6$

I know $p$ must be prime, but I'm just having trouble going forward.

Comment: About the formatting, try something like (2^p-1)^{-1} to write what you want. I don't really understand what you mean with the two expressions you wrote..

Comment: `2^{p-1}` gives you $2^{p-1}$, the curly brackets group things. It seems you know that every even perfect number is of the form $2^{p-1}\cdot (2^p-1)$, where $2^p-1$ is prime. Now, if $2^{p-1}(2^p-1) > 6$, what does that imply about $p$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget about the case p=2. Then, p is prime implies: p is odd. It's easy to prove that when p is odd you have:

2^p ≡ 2 (mod 6).

It's so because 2*4 ≡ 2 (mod 6) so you can go to any odd power and keep the residue at 2.

The same way you prove that 2^(p-1) ≡ 4 (mod 6).

That's it.

(2^(p-1))(2^p - 1) ≡ (4)(2-1) ≡ 4 (mod 6).

Comment: The condition $n > 6$ rules out $p = 2$.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Thanks.